# Replacing space with ,space in a string

Tags: java, string

I have a string `"ross rachael"`.

I need `"ross, rachael"`.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 7):

Use [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
String s = "ross rachael";
s.replace(" ", ", ");
```

If you want to replace all occurrences of whitespace by `", "`, you could use [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String s = "ross rachael";
s.replaceAll("\\s+", ", ");
```

Note that `\s` will match more than `" "`, it will match [any](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) whitespace character, `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`.

Comment: Or use `replaceAll()` with `\\s` instead of ` `, for more robust solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more robust solution (that deals with multi-spaces and tabs as well) you can use a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), and [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String s = "ross      racheal";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\s+",", "));
```

results in:

```
ross, racheal
```

The regex `\\s+` means: `\\` is breaking the special java meaning of `\`, providing a single `\` to the regex engine. `\s` is any white space. The + means one or more.

So the expression `\\s+` is actually one or more white spaces.